# Tooltips flash and disappear

Tags: macos, cocoa, tooltip, subclass

I am deploying tooltips in one of my OS X application.

I have made an image button class which is a subclass of NSImageView. Other things are working fine except for the tooltip. Currently, I add tooltip to the image button by using its superclass's setTooltip: method. But most of the time, when I hover mouse on the image button and want to get its tooltip, the tooltip just flashes and then disappears quickly.

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the initial delay of the tooltip as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"NSInitialToolTipDelay"];
```